# How to get all child categories of current parent category in product detail page of woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, categories

I have a product in child category of a parent category , there are many other sibling of that child category , I want to show them separately in current product page.

Clothes (parent) > (child)
Shirts
Bottoms
Socks

in every product of socks category I want to show shirts , bottoms and socks category separately.